# How to match a nested list with list

Tags: python, list, match, nested-lists

The problem is I'm trying to compare nested list and list without the same value or element ?

```
lst3 = [1, 6, 7, 10, 13, 28]
lst4 = [[13, 17, 18, 21, 32], [7, 11, 13, 14, 28], [1, 5, 6, 8, 15, 16]] 

lst5 = [list(filter(lambda x: x not in lst3, sublist)) for sublist in lst4]
```

which returns:

```
[[17, 18, 21, 32], [11, 14], [5, 8, 15, 16]]
```

but I would like to get the number that don't match from l3. Here an example:

```
[[1,6,7,10,28],[1,6,10],[1,7,13,28]]
```

I would like the results to be:
    `[[1,6,7,10,28],[1,6,10],[1,7,13,28]]`

Comment: Add the language as a tag please.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are comparing each element in each `sublist` with `lst3`.

> lst5 = [list(filter(lambda x: x not in lst3, sublist)) for sublist in lst4]

Problem is that you are asking whether each `x` from `sublist` is not in `lst3` which is going to give you the remaining results from the `sublist`. You may want to do it the other way around.

> lst5 = [list(filter(lambda x: x not in sublist, lst3)) for sublist in lst4]

Not only does it give you the answers you want but I even noticed you made a mistake in your expected results:

> [[1, 6, 7, 10, 28], [1, 6, 10], [7, 10, 13, 28]]

Compared to yours:

> [[1, 6, 7, 10, 28], [1, 6, 10], [1, 7,  13, 28]]

(See the last nested array)

Online example:
https://onlinegdb.com/Hy8K8GPSB

Comment: This actually works thanks. So the difference was the brackets?

Comment: No, in your expected results you wrote 1 instead of 10. (If that is what you were referring to)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using things like `filter` and `lambda`, you could more readably just use a list comprehension:

```
lst5 = [[x for x in lst3 if not x in sublist] for sublist in lst4]
```

Which is

```
[[1, 6, 7, 10, 28], [1, 6, 10], [7, 10, 13, 28]]
```

This differs slightly from what you gave as your expected output, but I think that you made a typographical error in the third sublist of that expected output.

Comment: This method works too. Do you know how to match two list that are two dimensional list?

Comment: @Sofreshnclean It is not quite clear what you mean by "match two lists that are two dimensional". You could perhaps accept one of the answers to this question and ask a new question which focuses on the modified problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would take John Coleman's answer but tweak the word order for readability.

`lst5 = [[x for x in lst3 if x not in sublist] for sublist in lst4]`

Answer (score 0):

I have two list that are two dimensional list with at least 100 rows. I would like to match c1 to c2 or vice versa. But the real problem is instead of typing in row by row from c1 to match c2. Is there a faster way to loop through all the rows from c1 to match all the rows from c2 ?

I tried c1[0] and c1[1] and c1[2]. This method will work but i would have to do alot of typing row by row. This will be to much typing especially if its alot of rows?

Here i have two list that are two dimensional list.

c1 = [[2, 6, 7],[2,4,6],[3,6,8]].....

c2 = [[13, 17, 18], [7, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8]].......

[list(filter(lambda x: x in c3, sublist)) for sublist in c2].

Comment: An answer to one question isn't the same as a new question. Why not just ask a new question?